# How can I get the R.drawable.image_sample under ImageView -> LinearLayout android?

Tags: java, android

How can I get the R.drawable.image_sample under ImageView -> LinearLayout?

I want to get the image under specific LinearLayout but I don't have an idea on how to this.

LinearLayout
 -> ImageView
    -> **R.drawable.image_sample**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want to do it in Xml or programmatically in Java code?

Comment: In java code @Nitin Sethi

Comment: layout.getChildAt(0) but from there i dont know whats next. i dont know how to get the R.drawable.image_sample from there.

Answer (score 0):

ImageView myImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.your_image_view_id_you_have_set_in_your_xml_layout);

Get the instance of the ImageView and use the method described below on that instance.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageResource(int)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I really appreciate it but what I need is to get the current image set on that ImageView assuming that the image is randomly set / changing randomly by other event listener. did you get my point? Thanks

Comment: Try getDrawable() on the ImageView instance.

Answer (score 0):

```
       you just need to use
       android:background="@drawable/image_sample" 
       in imageview
```

or

```
              you can use 
              android:src="@drawable/image_sample"
```